# How to send DHCP server a different hostname than the machine's static host name?

Tags: linux, dhcp

I'm using an at-home-type wireless router as the DHCP server for my desktop, with said router's management console showing the host names of the connected machines.  If I put `send host-name "AAA";` into `dhclient.conf` *and* my desktop has no static hostname then the router will show the hostname as "AAA".  However, if I then set the desktop's static hostname to "BBB" the router will show the hostname as "BBB", even though I want to stay as "AAA".  I tried using `send dhcp-client-identifier "AAA";`, but that confused the router so much it forgets any hostname and just shows the desktop's MAC address.

If it makes any difference, I'm using Fedora 24, and dhclient is launched/managed by NetworkManager.

Yes, I know there's no technical reason to give my at-home desktop a static hostname, nor for the router to display a different hostname.  I'm just weird and finicky about such things.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "static hostname", and where are you setting it?

Comment: The name changed via `hostnamectl --static`

Answer (score 0):

Your router is simply using the information your device makes available to show you the best possible name for the machine.

Since the information you provide mismatches, it knows it is unreliable and decides to only show the information that is verified: the MAC address.

There is absolutely no case where this should be a source of worry or take more than 2 seconds of your time.

Comment: This answer is wrong, doesn't answer the question, and attempts to shame OP for asking it (even after OP said he knows his requirements are peculiar). It's like a perfect example of exactly the kind of answer we *don't* want on this site.

Comment: I disagree.  I was stunned by your comment and reread my answer and I do not see where I appear to be shaming OP and it was not my intention.  If you have a better answer, you are more than welcome to post it but I think mine is valid and polite.